# How to access all children of linearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

I have imageviews inside a linearlayout. I am trying to get all the imageviews(children) when its parent(linearlayout) is clicked. Could you please tell me how to access all the children of linearlayout when the linearlayout is clicked?

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have searched before asking, while you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/linerLayout"
    >

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
       />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textId"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.macchhindra.stackoverflowexample;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 LinearLayout linearLayout;
 TextView myTextView;
 ImageView myImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linerLayout);
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textId);
        myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /// change your Image view image in this section
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
       LinearLayout ll =findViewById(R.id.linear);
    final int childCount = ll.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
    }
```